# How can I restrict number of Concurrent users on JBoss 4.0.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Jboss 4.0.4 GA
Apache 2.2

Comment: What metric do you use to tell you how many concurrent users there are right now?  Number of sessions active?  Number of active threads?

Answer (score 0):

OK, not very sure, but some googling led me to this:
Inside JBOSS_HOME\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml, look for the following.

`Connector port="8080"
address="${jboss.bind.address}"
maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"`

Modify the `maxThreads` parameter. Hopefully this would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to handle the case when the limit is reached: Show a "please wait" page? Drop the connection? Hold the connection in a queue? I'd suggest to focus on:

1) Application / framework specific
2) acceptCount
3) maxThreads

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to reject the sessions at the front end (Apache 2.2 has a few modules to limit session count)